# db_stat not working correctly for Berkeley DB

Tags: c, berkeley-db

I downloaded Berkeley DB `5.3.28` and `18.1.40` from Oracle, compiled on Ubuntu 18.04 successfully. Everything worked as expected except `db_stat` utility doesn't want to return correct database statistics for me. Particularly, no of unique keys, no of data items, etc... are all wrong.

Here is my test code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <db.h>


int main() {
  DB *dbp;
  DBT key, data;
  int ret, t_ret;

  ret = db_create(&dbp, NULL, 0);
    assert(ret == 0);

  ret = dbp->open(dbp, NULL, "sample.db", "", DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE, 0664);
  assert(ret == 0);

  memset(&key, 0, sizeof(key));
  memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));
  key.data = (char*)"fruit";
  key.size = sizeof("fruit");
  data.data = (char*)"apple";
  data.size = sizeof("apple");

  ret = dbp->put(dbp, NULL, &key, &data, 0);
  assert(ret == 0);

  key.data = (char*)"color";
  key.size = sizeof("color");
  data.data = (char*)"red";
  data.size = sizeof("red");

  ret = dbp->put(dbp, NULL, &key, &data, 0);
  assert(ret == 0);

  key.data = (char*)"language";
  key.size = sizeof("language");
  data.data = (char*)"c";
  data.size = sizeof("c");

  ret = dbp->put(dbp, NULL, &key, &data, 0);
  assert(ret == 0);

  dbp->close(dbp, 0);
}
```

db_stat output:

> db_stat -d sample.db

```
Sun Jun  7 20:26:59 2020    Local time
53162   Btree magic number
9   Btree version number
Little-endian   Byte order
multiple-databases  Flags
2   Minimum keys per-page
4096    Underlying database page size
1007    Overflow key/data size
1   Number of levels in the tree
1   Number of unique keys in the tree
1   Number of data items in the tree
0   Number of tree internal pages
0   Number of bytes free in tree internal pages (0% ff)
1   Number of tree leaf pages
4054    Number of bytes free in tree leaf pages (1% ff)
0   Number of tree duplicate pages
0   Number of bytes free in tree duplicate pages (0% ff)
0   Number of tree overflow pages
0   Number of bytes free in tree overflow pages (0% ff)
0   Number of empty pages
0   Number of pages on the free list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named your database `""` in the `dbp->open` call.  So, you have to pass that to `db_stat` too, with the `-s` flag:

```
$ db_stat -d sample.db -s ""
Wed Jun 10 03:16:43 2020    Local time
53162   Btree magic number
9   Btree version number
Little-endian   Byte order
record-numbers, multiple-databases  Flags
2   Minimum keys per-page
8192    Underlying database page size
2031    Overflow key/data size
1   Number of levels in the tree
3   Number of unique keys in the tree
3   Number of data items in the tree
0   Number of tree internal pages
0   Number of bytes free in tree internal pages (0% ff)
1   Number of tree leaf pages
8090    Number of bytes free in tree leaf pages (1% ff)
0   Number of tree duplicate pages
0   Number of bytes free in tree duplicate pages (0% ff)
0   Number of tree overflow pages
0   Number of bytes free in tree overflow pages (0% ff)
0   Number of empty pages
0   Number of pages on the free list
```

(My BDB defaulted to an 8K page, but is otherwise the same.)

Comment: Many thanks, I would not have know passing empty string would be the thing :)